# Drupal 8/9 htaccess Breaks kcfinder

Tags: civimail, kcfinder

There are other discussions on this but there does not appear to be a concrete solution. I am hoping that someone can help me with a solution and then I can also document this better.

When I go to add an image to an email with kcfinder *Browse Server* option I get a popup with a 404.

The URL in the popup https://crm.mysite.org/libraries/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/browse.php?cms=civicrm&type=images&CKEditor=crmUiId_1&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=en appears to be correct.

This has me thinking that the issue is the Drupal htaccess rules.

The files for kcfinder were not in the libraries/civicrm/packages/kcfinder folder by default but I added the files from another Drupal 8 install.

I am not sure there is other information I can provide that would be of use to solve this.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: It sounds like `composer civicrm:publish` didn't run properly during install. You can try running that on its own.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not change anything.  Thanks!

Comment: Quick update: There are currently two issues regarding this bug: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/civicrm-asset-plugin/-/issues/4 and https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3419. Also a possible workaround is described here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40231/ckeditor-drupal9-gives-403-forbidden-when-browsing-server

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue called [kcfinder libraries is missing files](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/civicrm-asset-plugin/-/issues/4) and presently this issue is open with no resolution.

Bottom line: There is a bug in CiviCRM with Drupal 9 and KCFinder.